# esta sentencia no me funciona

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysqli, sqlite

he probado esta sentencia de varias formas incluso con otras columnas pero en la unica que no me muestra nada y necesito que me muestre es esta en la que necesito que me muestre los receptores en este caso
la sentencia es esta:

```
SELECT * FROM mensaje WHERE receptor = "[cualquier correo de la bbdd da igual cual ponga ninguno sale]" ORDER BY fecha;
```

ya he probado dobles comillas comillas simples sin el order by y nada no me muestra la columna receptores pero si el resto y no se por que
aqui adjunto la tabla en la que estoy intentando usar la sentencia,
aqui adjunto el codigo exportado del workbench de la tabla mensaje y la tabla usuario

```
        -- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.19, for Win64 (x86_64)
    --
    -- Host: 127.0.0.1    Database: mychat
    -- ------------------------------------------------------
    -- Server version   8.0.19

    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
    /*!50503 SET NAMES utf8 */;
    /*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
    /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
    /*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
    /*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
    /*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

    --
    -- Table structure for table `usuarios`
    --

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `usuarios`;
    /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
    /*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
    CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
      `correo` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
      `nombre` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `contraseña` varchar(45) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `usuarios`
    --

    LOCK TABLES `usuarios` WRITE;
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `usuarios` DISABLE KEYS */;
    INSERT INTO `usuarios` VALUES ('sebaselpresi@yolo.com','Sebas','tusebira69'),('borjitaxurrita@iralo.com','Borja','sabrosura1234'),('francisquillomozuelo@pontonse.com','Fran','alcampo999'),('correoprueba@chupala.es','admin','admin1234'),('pepvilluela12@keke.es','pepe','34frenchi34'),('josemaria@mychat.com','josemaria','12jose12maria'),('josemaria@mychat.com','josemaria','wdsftgbs'),('josemaria@mychat.com','josemaria','sdfgds'),('Sebas@mychat.com','Sebas','dferfgas'),('cristobal@mychat.com','cristobal','mepartolapolla12veces');
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `usuarios` ENABLE KEYS */;
    UNLOCK TABLES;
    /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

    /*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
    /*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
    /*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
    /*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

    -- Dump completed on 2020-02-20 20:15:05


    -- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.19, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1    Database: mychat
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   8.0.19

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `mensaje`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mensaje`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `mensaje` (
  `emisor` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `receptor` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `texto` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `id_mensaje` int NOT NULL,
  `estado` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_mensaje`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `mensaje`
--

LOCK TABLES `mensaje` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `mensaje` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `mensaje` VALUES ('sebaselpresi@yolo.com\r\n','borjitaxurrita@iralo.com\r\n','Tio ayer se me olvido enviarte el material pincha aqui www.timagina.jar.com','2020-02-13',1,0),('francisquillomozuelo@pontonse.com\r\n','borjitaxurrita@iralo.com\r\n','Mira las fotos que he subido a mega de la fiesta de ayer www.mega.ns/mynube','2020-02-13',2,0),('francisquillomozuelo@pontonse.com','sebaselpresi@yolo.com\r\n','Sebas necesito que me traigas el raton que te deje que el mio se me ha roto','2020-02-13',3,1),('borjitaxurrita@iralo.com\r\n','francisquillomozuelo@pontonse.com\r\n','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua','2020-02-13',4,1),('pedro','luis','hola','2020-02-20',5,0);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `mensaje` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2020-02-20 20:31:03
```

Comment: estás en efecto usando comillas dobles (`"`) en tu query para indicar un string en vez de comillas simples (`'`)?

Comment: he probado de las 2 formas pero ninguna funciona

Comment: no es necesario probar con comillas dobles, ya que deben ser comillas simples. Y sólo para verificar, no estás usando paréntesis cuadrados dentro del texto que estás buscando, cierto? (`[correo@algo.com]`)

Comment: @Lamak ya esta añadida

Comment: Y los estás insertando con los literales `\r\n`?

Comment: como? no entiendo yo lo que hago es copiar el nombre del registro en este caso de cualquier receptor le doy a copiar meto el email entre comillas y le doy a ejecutar la query vamos como tengo puesto al principio de la pregunta

Comment: pusiste este email como ejemplo: `'sebaselpresi@yolo.com\r\n'`, después estás buscando por ese texto idéntico?

Comment: ya encontre la solucion y era el charset que lo tenia que poner unicode, gracias igualmente